# Mobile Broadband disconnects as soon as connected - Crunchbang

Tags: debian, modem, crunchbang, mobile

For months now my mobile broadband (GSM) stick has worked with Crunchbang. Yesterday it stopped. When I plug it in, it appears in the network manager and I can connect to it, but as soon as it is connected it disconnects.

I switched to Liquorix kernel about 1.5 weeks ago and the stick worked with it as well, until now. Switching back to the original kernel does not fix it.

Computer:
Lenovo U410

GSM stick:
Sierra Wireless USB 308

Has anyone run into this before and knows how to fix it?

EDIT: Added dmesg output

```
usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-1: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 9 but max is 0
usb 1-1: config 1 has no interface number 0
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1199, idProduct=0fff
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
usb 1-1: Product: USB MMC Storage
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
usb 1-1: SerialNumber: SWOC22905731
usb-storage 1-1:1.9: USB Mass Storage device detected
usb-storage: probe of 1-1:1.9 failed with error -5
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
usb 1-1: config 1 has an invalid interface number: 7 but max is 4
usb 1-1: config 1 has no interface number 2
usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1199, idProduct=68a3
usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
usb 1-1: Product: USB 308
usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Sierra Wireless, Incorporated
usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 355385035042361
sierra 1-1:1.0: Sierra USB modem converter detected
usb 1-1: Sierra USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB0
sierra 1-1:1.1: Sierra USB modem converter detected
usb 1-1: Sierra USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB1
sierra 1-1:1.3: Sierra USB modem converter detected
usb 1-1: Sierra USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB2
sierra 1-1:1.4: Sierra USB modem converter detected
usb 1-1: Sierra USB modem converter now attached to ttyUSB3
usb 1-1: Incompatible driver and firmware versions
usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 6
sierra ttyUSB2: resubmit read urb failed.(-19)
sierra ttyUSB2: resubmit read urb failed.(-19)
sierra ttyUSB2: resubmit read urb failed.(-19)
sierra ttyUSB2: resubmit read urb failed.(-19)
sierra ttyUSB2: resubmit read urb failed.(-19)
sierra ttyUSB2: resubmit read urb failed.(-19)
sierra ttyUSB2: resubmit read urb failed.(-19)
sierra ttyUSB2: resubmit read urb failed.(-19)
sierra ttyUSB0: Sierra USB modem converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
sierra 1-1:1.0: device disconnected
sierra ttyUSB1: Sierra USB modem converter now disconnected from ttyUSB1
sierra 1-1:1.1: device disconnected
sierra ttyUSB2: Sierra USB modem converter now disconnected from ttyUSB2
sierra 1-1:1.3: device disconnected
sierra ttyUSB3: Sierra USB modem converter now disconnected from ttyUSB3
sierra 1-1:1.4: device disconnected
```

EDIT: Trying to set `usb_modeswitch`:

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 119 -p 68a3 -S
```

Output from that:

```
Looking for default devices ...
    No devices in default mode found. Nothing to do. Bye.
```

EDIT: Fixed typo in the `usb_modeswitch` command

```
sudo usb_modeswitch -v 1199 -p 68a3 -S
```

The command ran properly that time but to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing the device on multiple computers and multiple OS's it would seem that there are hardware problems with the broadband stick.